# Application is not showing in full screen in xcode 6 simulator using SHViewPager?

Tags: objective-c

[image]I am using SHViewPager library to swipe between viewcontroller? But the application is not showing in full screen? Right side is blank? Can anyone help regarding? I am using the same code provided in the example to test but it still appear blank on right side.

Comment: The application is showing in fullscreen in iphone4 and 5 but right side blank in iphone6.

Comment: I solved this issue by increasing the size of xib file. This can be managed more clearly using storyboard and using autolayout.